# Export data from SQL2005 stored procedure to CSV

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, csv, reporting

I want to find a way to allow our reporting guy to export data returned from a stored procedure into a CSV file.  The procedure will need a (date) parameter passing to it.

Is there a data export wizard I can get him to use, or some other user friendly way in SQL2005 that he can generate the CSV (after providing some parameters).

It isn't absolutley necessary that the data must come from a stored procedure, it could be a view or something, but he must be able to easily provide some preset constraints when generating the CSV file.

Thanks for any assistance you guys can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what tools you are looking at, just give him SQL Server Management Studio.  He can then execute the stored procedure and save the results in a CSV format.  That is your most elegant way to be able to do it in a dynamic fashion.

Otherwise, you might look at creating an SSIS package if the values don't change often.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SQL Server Reporting services. You can export the results of a report to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a small web app with a couple filter options and a button to export to excel.

That would remove the any reliance on your reporting persons abilities to work within SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

try

sqlcmd -S Servername (-E or -U -p) -d database -Q"exec storedprocedure" -s ","-o filename

from a command line

Comment: sqlcmd (&osql) are command line interfaces to sql server

-S specifies the server name 

-E specifies using your current windows credentials to login 

or use  

-U sql login -P sqlpassword

-Q"sql statement" is the sql statement you wish to run then it exits

-d is the database you wish to use

ordinarily the results of that statement are returned to the screen but  -o outputs them to a text file 

-s is a separator placed between data items (column values) on each row, in this case a comma
This is a nailed on, bona fide, dba certified method of exporting sql queries to a csv